# Threading Error

Tags: android, multithreading, android-thread

I get some error. I really couldn't solve it today :( I get error after set ID data to lblID in FillData() method. It sets ID data properly but lblTitle and lblPrice always returns error like "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" and program stops running.

**Note :** This is not my original code. I just minimized it to be more understandable and of course it gives same error like below code. Anyway in FillData() method i get data from wcf service and it returns data properly. i tried runonuithread but it didn't make any sense. Also if i write the code outside of the thread it doesn't fill the controls. Because it's originally gets the data from wcf service.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LinearLayout lytData;
TextView lblTitle, lblID, lblPrice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    lytData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lytNewData);
    lblID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblID);
    lblTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTitle); 
    lblPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblPrice); 
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            FillData();
        }
    }.start();

    lytData.setOnTouchListener(new OnCustomTouchListener (context) {
        @Override
        public void ToLeft() {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    FillData();
                }
            }.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void ToRight() {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    FillData();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}

void FillData() {
   lblID.setText("aaa");
   lblTitle.setText("aaa");
   lblPrice.setText("aaa");
}
```

Comment: If you need to change the UI in anyways from a Thread, you should use runonuithread() and perform your change inside the runnable you pass to it, i'll let you search for examples there is plenty of them on google.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to update the UI in another thread, but the UI can only be updated in the UI thread. If you're simply updated the UI as your code is showing then  you should remove the calls from FillData from the secondary thread, use a secondary thread if you're doing heavy loading inside `FillData()` otherwise you're better off updating the UI directly in the UI thread:
So instead of doing this:

```
   new Thread() {
      public void run() {
         FillData();
         pd.cancel();
      }
    }.start();
```

Just simply call  FillData(); outside the new thread.

You can also call runOnUiThread to bring the update to the ui thread:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        FillData();
    }
});
```

If your code inside FillData is mixed with heavy load code, then you can bring the `runOnUiThread` method to inside the `FillData` and move only the UI update code to `runOnUiThread`.

If you still want to keep your code the way it is you can "post" changes from your secondary thread like this:

```
viewElement.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //update UI
        }
    });
}
```

`viewElement` is any UI element that extends from `View`.

Comment: downvoter please be constructive to the community and explain why you've downvoted

Comment: I first downvoted because your answer was "do your modification out of your thread" wich is useless, if the OP is doing that in a thread he must have reasons to do so, then you added the runonuithread() solution, wich is for me the good one so i removed my vote.

Comment: If you check the OP  FillData(); method there's no reason for them to be doing that in another thread, they might have a reason of course, but from what they've posted that reason isn't clear therefore we can advise them to what would be the best approach.

Comment: It's not your job to extrapolate on what he may or may not need as it's not the question asked here, you can suggest of course, but this was also not a suggestion the way you wrote it, i won't go further as i believe you got my point and arguing on that is useless anyway.

Comment: yeah, I could argue more, but nah ;)

Comment: This is not my original code. I just minimized it to be more understandable and of course it gives same error like above example. Anyway in FillData() method i get data from wcf service and it returns data properly. i tried runonuithread but it didn't make any sense. Also if i write the code outside of the thread it doesn't fill the controls. Because it's originally gets the data from wcf service.

Comment: Awwww I get it. Then you should put inside on runOnUiThread only the code that updates the UI or use the "post" approach. Sorry, I thought you only had the UI update code

Comment: i couldn't solve the problem but i added following codes after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); step in onCreate method and now everything works fine. StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);